# How can I create a new "link document" on sharePoint via C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, hyperlink

I have a Folder in sharepoint with a lot of files (word, pp, excel, etc.)

The clients upload their files to this folder via asp.net application (c#).

Now they would like option to do a "linked document", for example, if they have a word document that call "Test.docx", They want that when they try to upload it agaom, the file will not be overwritten, but will create a new document which is a link to the actual document.

In sharePoint website I have a option to do a "linked file", and The file created with "aspx" suffix.

but I dont find how to do this through the code.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

The following code for your reference.

```
public class LinkToDocument
{

   public static readonly Guid g_guidIconOverride = new Guid("{B77CDBCF-5DCE-4937-85A7-9FC202705C91}");
   public static readonly string FLD_URL = "URL";

   /// <param name="name">file name</param>
   /// <param name="urlVal">Url del link</param>
   /// <param name="overrideIcon">file extension for the file icon</param>
   public static SPListItem CreateLinkToDocumentFile(SPDocumentLibrary list, string name, SPFieldUrlValue urlVal, string overrideIcon = null)
   {
      var docType = list.ContentTypes.Cast<SPContentType>().Single(ct => ct.Id.IsChildOf(SPBuiltInContentTypeId.LinkToDocument));
      return CreateLinkToDocumentFile(list, docType.Id, name, urlVal, overrideIcon);
   }

   public static SPListItem CreateLinkToDocumentFile(SPDocumentLibrary list, SPContentTypeId contentTypeId, string name, SPFieldUrlValue urlVal, string overrideIcon = null)
   {
      SPContentType contentType = list.ContentTypes[contentTypeId];
      string extension = "";
      if (urlVal != null && urlVal.Url != null) extension = Path.GetExtension((urlVal.Url).Trim()).TrimStart(".".ToCharArray());
      SPFolder currentFolder = list.RootFolder;
      SPFileCollection files = currentFolder.Files;
      string fileUrl = string.Concat(currentFolder.Url, "/", name, ".aspx");
      string fileTemplate = "<%@ Assembly Name='{0}' %>\r\n <%@ Register TagPrefix='SharePoint' Namespace='Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls' Assembly='Microsoft.SharePoint' %>\r\n <%@ Import Namespace='System.IO' %>\r\n <%@ Import Namespace='Microsoft.SharePoint' %>\r\n <%@ Import Namespace='Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities' %>\r\n <%@ Import Namespace='Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls' %>\r\n <html>\r\n <head> <meta name='progid' content='SharePoint.Link' /> </head>\r\n <body>\r\n <form id='Form1' runat='server'>\r\n <SharePoint:UrlRedirector id='Redirector1' runat='server' />\r\n </form>\r\n </body>\r\n </html>";
      StringBuilder fileContent = new StringBuilder(fileTemplate.Length + 400);
      fileContent.AppendFormat(fileTemplate, typeof(SPDocumentLibrary).Assembly.FullName);
      Hashtable properties = new Hashtable();
      SPContentTypeId ctId = contentType.Id;
      properties["ContentTypeId"] = ctId.ToString();
      SPFile file = files.Add(fileUrl, new MemoryStream((new UTF8Encoding()).GetBytes(fileContent.ToString())), properties, false, false);
      SPListItem item = file.Item;
      item[FLD_URL] = urlVal;
      if (list.Fields.Contains(g_guidIconOverride)) item[g_guidIconOverride] = string.Concat("|", overrideIcon ?? extension, "|");
      item.IconOverlay = "linkoverlay.gif";
      item.UpdateOverwriteVersion();
      return item;
   }
}
```

More information is here: [SHAREPOINT 2013: CREATE "LINK TO A DOCUMENT" PROGRAMMATICALLY](https://erroreimprevisto.wordpress.com/2014/05/10/sharepoint-2013-programmatically-add-link-to-a-document-file-in-a-document-library/)

CSOM code as below.

```
string docLinkTemplate = null;
using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader("SharePointDocLinkTemplate.txt"))
{
    docLinkTemplate = sr.ReadToEnd();
}

string docLink = "http://myserver/test.doc";
docLinkTemplate = String.Format(docLinkTemplate, docLink);

FileCreationInformation fileCreateInfo = new FileCreationInformation();
fileCreateInfo.Content = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(docLinkTemplate);
fileCreateInfo.Url = "testlinkfordoc.doc.aspx";
File file = list.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileCreateInfo);
ListItem fileListItem = file.ListItemAllFields;
fileListItem["ContentType"] = "Link to a Document";
FieldUrlValue urlValue = new FieldUrlValue();
urlValue.Description = "Link to doc test";
urlValue.Url = docLink;
fileListItem["URL"] = urlValue;
context.Load(file);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```